# Array retorna nada

Tags: c, array, if, for

Estou tentando fazer que um array armazene a letra digitada se não for uma vogal, no entanto, ele não está armazenando nada, aparece apenas uns símbolos estranhos. Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    char letra[10], consoante[10];
    int i, x = 0;

    printf("Faca um Programa que leia um vetor de 10 caracteres, e diga quantas consoantes foram lidas. Imprima as consoantes\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite a letra: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &letra[i]);

        if ((letra[i] == 'a') || (letra[i] == 'e') || (letra[i] == 'i') || letra[i] == 'o' || letra[i] == 'u')
        {
            printf("Caiu aqui");
        }
        else
        {
            consoante[i] == letra[i];
        }
    }

    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
       printf("A consoante foi: %c\n", consoante[x]);
    }


    system("pause");
}
```

Já testei o `if` e o `else` e está caindo no local correto, mas não armazena no *array*.

Comment: Você está utilizando a mesma variável índice e portanto está deixando as posições que contém vogais com lixo de memória no array consoante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem vários problemas aí. O primeiro é que não precisa ter dois *array*s, de acordo com o que descreveu. Há um erro sintático/semântico quando tenta atribuir um valor com `==`, esse é o operador de comparação. E o código acaba sendo mais complexo do que precisa ser e aí acaba criando um *array* cheio de buracos mas ainda assim acessa todas as 10 posições. Você tem que controlar o contador de quantas consoantes existem no *array* e só ler essas, inclusive porque o exercício pede para imprimir esse total e seu código não o faz. O teste que fez fazia justamente cair no lugar errado, o `if` é invertido.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char consoante[10];
    int total = 0;
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Digite a letra: ");
        char letra;
        scanf("%c", &letra);
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
        if (letra != 'a' && letra != 'e' && letra != 'i' && letra != 'o' && letra != 'u') consoante[total++] = letra;
    }
    printf("\n%d", total);
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) printf("\nA consoante foi: %c", consoante[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Li3LVM). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/elsvtfjq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/FilterLetters.c).

Usei um método universal para limpar o *buffer*, o que usou só funciona em certas situações.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    char letra[10], consoante[10];
    int i, x = 0, contaNumeroDeConsoantes = 0;;


    printf("Faca um Programa que leia um vetor de 10 caracteres, e diga quantas consoantes foram lidas. Imprima as consoantes\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite a letra: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &letra[i]);

        if ((letra[i] == 'a') || (letra[i] == 'e') || (letra[i] == 'i') || letra[i] == 'o' || letra[i] == 'u')
        {
            printf("Caiu aqui");
        }
        else
        {
            consoante[contaNumeroDeConsoantes ] = letra[i];
            contaNumeroDeConsoantes = contaNumeroDeConsoantes + 1; 
        }
    }

    for (x = 0; x < contaNumeroDeConsoantes ; x++)
    {
       printf("A consoante foi: %c\n", consoante[x]);
    }


    system("pause");
}
```

**EXPLICAÇÃO**
No seu código havia um erro na linha `consoante[i] == letra[i];` para atribuir um valor utiliza o `=` e não `==`, e esses símbolos estranhos que você disse ter visto, é simplesmente porque você estava tentando acessar índices do vetor `consoantes` que não existiam, pois o `for (x = 0; x < 10; x++){printf("A consoante foi: %c\n", consoante[x]);}` sempre "acharia" que `consoante` tem 10 valores, o que nem sempre aconteceria, pois imagine que você passasse os valores nessa ordem: A,B,C,D,E,I,O,U,A,A, os únicos valores que deviam estar na variável `consoante` é `consoante[0]->B`, `consoante[1]->C` e `consoante[2]-D`,ou seja o `for` de exibição do vetor `consoante` deve ser somente até 3, e não até 10, por isso foi declarado uma nova variável chamada `contaNumeroDeConsoantes`, variável que é incrementada sempre que você digitar uma consoante.

**E O QUE ERAM OS SÍMBOLOS?** Quando você declara uma variável em C, ele salva essa variável em alguma parte da memória, exemplo: `consoante[0] = 1 -> (local da variável poderia ser 215 na memória)`, e se você tentar fazer `consoante[293]` esse valor vai ser de outro lugar da memória. Quando você começar a ver ponteiros talvez entenda melhor