# Alocação de memória para vetor de strings com malloc()

Tags: c, array, memória

Este código abaixo, pede um `num` para a quantidade de `strings` que eu quero armazenar no `vetor` que neste caso é o ponteiro `char *strings[num]`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    char *strings[num];
    void string_alunos(char *strings[], int num);

    printf("Quantas strings voce deseja armazenar? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Digite as palavras:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        strings[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
        if (strings[i] != NULL)
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%30[^\n]", strings[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("*** Não foi possível alocar memoria! ***");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    string_alunos(strings, num);
    free(strings);

    return 0;
}
void string_alunos(char *strings[], int num)
{
    printf("\n::: PALAVRAS :::\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Ao utilizar o `malloc()` eu quero uma string de no máximo 30 caracteres. Com o `malloc()` na teoria ele deveria reservar 30 bytes na memória. certo? Ou não?
Enfim, eu rodei o *debug mode*, e as posições entre as *strings* dão um total de 56 bytes de diferença entre uma e outra, por que isso acontece? Não deveria ter uma diferença de 30 bytes?

[image: Imagem do debug mode adicionado os endereços de memória]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O principal problema é que está inicializando o *array* com tamanho 0 então só vai corromper a memória colocando coisas onde nada foi reservado. Mandando a inicialização dele depois que já sabe o tamanho que ele deve ter resolve isso.

Existe um problema que não é grave em um exercício assim, mas já que foi fazer a liberação então libere algo correto. `strings` nunca foi alocado com `malloc()` então não faz sentido dar `free()` nela, mas todos elementos dela foram inicializado com `malloc()` então deve dar `free()` em todos. Eu até não teria criado a função para escrever na tela, porque aí teve que fazer 2 laços sem necessidade.

Ainda tinha um erro no formatador da entrada de dados que eu corrigi.

E aloquei um caractere a mais para o terminador da *string*, caso contrário daria problema em alguns casos.

Tirei algumas coisas que não fazem sentido ou é inócuo ou até errado fazer. Deve ter aprendido fazer assim em fontes ruins.

Não otimizei para evitar o `malloc()`. Já que o tamanho da *string* é conhecido poderia alocar tudo na pilha mesmo (embora seria bom validar o máximo), já que começou fazendo isto, e evitar o `malloc()` o que simplificaria o código, mas não sei bem qual é o objetivo. De qualquer forma faria mais sentido tudo na memória automática ou tudo na memória dinâmica.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void string_alunos(char *strings[], int num) {
    printf("\n::: PALAVRAS :::\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
}

int main() {
    int num;
    printf("Quantas strings voce deseja armazenar? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    char *strings[num];
    printf("\n");
    printf("Digite as palavras:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        strings[i] = malloc(31);
        if (strings[i] != NULL) scanf("%30s[^\n]", strings[i]);
        else {
            printf("*** Não foi possível alocar memoria! ***");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    string_alunos(strings, num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) free(strings[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bHd6GG). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/acbtetfo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/DeclareArray.c).

Comment: O código possui algumas coisas desnecessárias, como a função, por exemplo, pois o professor pediu no exercício dessa maneira. Enfim, só uma dúvida, você comentou que havia um erro no formatador de entrada, seria pq eu não coloquei aquele 's' ao lado do %30? se sim, o que seria esse 's'? Além disso, vc acabou retirando aquele fflush(stdin), se eu retiro isso, a execução pula direto para o final do programa qnd eu informo o número de strings, isso não seria para limpar o buffer do teclado? Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: O `s` diz que deve pegar uma *string*, sem ele não está dizendo o que pegar, tem implementação que pode funcionar por coincidência. Em C quase tudo pode funcionar por coincidência, mas precisa funcionar sempre. È o caso do `fflush()`, só funciona em certas implementações, não em todas, então não deve usar. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325628/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/453303/101 e

Comment: Opa, desculpe retornar aqui novamente.. mas eu estava testando aquilo que você havia comentado de colocar o tipo de dado que iria ler no scanf "scanf("%30s[^\n]", strings[i])" no caso aqui seria o 's' de string, porém, ao colocar isso na hora de retornar a string ela retorna somente o que está antes do espaço " ", se eu digito por exemplo, bola de basquete, retorna somente bola, se eu retiro esse 's' ele retorna a string inteira, você saberia uma forma de resolver? e para limpar o buffer do teclado agr estou utilizando o while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){}

Comment: Veja os *links* que eu passei, tem várias informações sobre isso, inclusive como é ineficaz ler frases com `scanf()`.

Comment: Pois é, eu dei uma olhada e vi que para ler os dados, pelo menos em exercícios simples assim o ideal é fgets(), porém não estou conseguindo utilizar ele no programa.. qual seria a forma correta de utilizar baseado nesse programa que eu fiz? dessa forma aqui: fgets(strings[i], 31, stdin) ela lê certinho, tipo se qro armazenar 3 strings, eu digito 'pedro' 'joao' 'gustavo', na saída sai 'pedro' 'gustavo' ele sempre está pulando uma linha, saberia como resolver isso?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216450/101